# How to block access to web camera for any programs including all Java applets?

Tags: webcam

There is need to deny interaction and access for built-in web camera from any application including trusted Java applications. For example, deny access to webcam for Skype etc. How to make it possible?

Comment: Unload the webcam driver/kernel module.

Comment: If you can physically remove the webcam, probably good. Beyond that, do what Marco suggested. Uninstall the Webcam Driver. But windows may be acting smart and re-install. Another option is go to "Computer Management" and "Disable" that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously removing the webcam is the most sure-fire ware to ensure no one uses it.  If that's not an option, disabling it in the OS should work well.  Removing the drivers would work temporarily but at the next system update they would almost definitely be re-installed.

If you're on Windows disabling the device is as simple as right clicking on the webcam and clicking "disable".

[image: screenshot]